# How to generate a random number within a min and max parameters in SASS?

Tags: random, sass, formula

How to generate a random number within a min and max parameters in SASS? For example a random number from 5 to 15.

```
.foo
  font-size: random(15)#{px}
```

If that is not possible, what would be a similar formula?

Thank you!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is no minimum value to set in SASS.

But you can tweak it as follows for a random number from 5 to 15.

```
.foo
  font-size: (random(11) + 4)+px
```

added 4 to 11, because `random()` function has minimum value of 1

Answer (score 20):

[There is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/363732/4306572) a standard pattern to generate random value in a range.

`Min + (int)(Math.random() * ((Max - Min) + 1))`

In scss it would look like:

```
@function randomNum($min, $max) {
  $rand: random();
  $randomNum: $min + floor($rand * (($max - $min) + 1));

  @return $randomNum;
}

.foo {
  font-size: #{randomNum(5, 10)}px;
}
```

Sassmeister [demo](http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/56375ccfc15cf7d9f769b6ddc0b33e7f).